# Minimizing the length of the confidence interval for the unknown normal mean with known variance

Tags: statistics

Reading through my Stats textbook, the author briefly talks about the minimal length of the confidence interval for the unknown normal mean with known variance. He states that the confidence interval with the shortest expected length is the symmetric one, i.e. the interval:
$$(\ \overline{Y} - z_{\alpha- \alpha_1}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \ , \ \overline{Y} + z_{\alpha_1}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \ ) $$  where $ \alpha_1 = \frac{\alpha}{2} $.

He claims the proof is obvious, but I have been having some trouble with it.

I know the expected value of the length of the interval is given by: 
$$ ( \ z_{\alpha_1} + z_{\alpha - \alpha_1} \ )\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\ \ . $$
From here on I'm not sure how to proceed with the proof. I know that 
$$ z_\alpha = \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha) \ \ . $$
I've tried plugging this into the above formula for expected value, but I'm not sure what to do from there. Do I somehow have to find the derivative of the quantile function? Is that even something that people use? I must be missing something simple and obvious. Thanks so much for any help you can give!

Comment: I agree it is obvious. The density of the standard normal is symmetric about $0$, and steadily decreasing for positive $z$. So if we want area say $0.95$, the shortest interval is obtained if we are using the "fat" part of the density function.

Comment: Wow, that's a really intuitive way of thinking about it, thanks! I'm trying to think how one might frame it more rigorously though...is there such a way to describe the "fatness"?

Comment: Sure, one can formally minimize $t-s$ given $\int_s^t f_Z(z)\,dz=k$, where $f_Z$ is the density function of the standard normal. Usual tools. But the geometry is clear.

Comment: I'll give it a shot! Thanks a bunch!